# tx_news n:link don't want build absolute link with config.absPrefix

Tags: tx-news, typo3-9.x

in tx_news template we have `<n:link`  which follow `<f:link.typolink` seems we can use `configuration="{forceAbsoluteUrl: 1}"` and get

```
<h3>
  <n:link configuration="{forceAbsoluteUrl: 1}" newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{settings}" title="{newsItem.title}">
    <span itemprop="headline">{newsItem.title}</span>
  </n:link>
</h3>
```

For build absolute link TYPO3 use `config.absPrefix` but no effect in TYPO3 9.5.3.  I can change this settings just in Site `Configuration -> Entry Point`. But not more in typoscript.

I've checked. This typoscript setting still available in TYPO3 9.5.3. But looks like work just for assets (scripts/styles in header) no more for links? Can i fix that?

In end i need absolute links in tx_news from  `config.absPrefix` or other typoscript but not config.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one solution from typoscript dont work in TYPO3 v9.5.x so I have to use `Site manager Variants`

```
rootPageId: 1
base: www.livedomain.com
baseVariants:
  -
    base: 'http://localhost'
    condition: 'applicationContext == "Development"'
  -
    base: 'https://stagedomain.com'
    condition: 'applicationContext == "Testing"'
```

And in my apache2 or .htaccess

```
SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Development
```

or

```
SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Testing
```

If context not set website use base url in other cases from baseVariants

Answer (score 2):

Try with `config.absRefPrefix` instead of `config.absPrefix`